# Query multiple records of a group that has max date....sorta

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Example code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID int, Name varchar(50), Date Datetime2)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID, Name, Date)
SELECT 1, 'abc', GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'def', GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'hij', GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', GETDATE()-2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'def', GETDATE()-2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'hij', GETDATE()-2
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'abc', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'def', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'hij', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'abc', GETDATE()-1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'def', GETDATE()-1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'hij', GETDATE()-1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'abc', GETDATE()-3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'def', GETDATE()-3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'hij', GETDATE()-3
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'abc', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'def', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'hij', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'abc', GETDATE()+2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'def', GETDATE()+2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'hij', GETDATE()+2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'abc', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'def', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'hij', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'abc', GETDATE()-5
UNION ALL   
SELECT 3, 'def', GETDATE()-5
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'hij', GETDATE()-5
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'abc', GETDATE()+1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'def', GETDATE()+1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'hij', GETDATE()+1
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'abc', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'def', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'hij', GETDATE()-4
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'abc', GETDATE()-5
UNION ALL   
SELECT 4, 'def', GETDATE()-5
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'hij', GETDATE()-5

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

The data output that I want reflects output of the following records

```
3   abc 2013-09-18 
3   def 2013-09-18 
3   hij 2013-09-18
```

Description: I would like to query the data for the ID/Name that was processed most recently (Max(Date)) (there can be multiple ID's if they were processed at the same date/time)

My try...

```
SELECT  DISTINCT A.*, B.My_Rank
FROM    @TABLE A
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT ID, Name, CONVERT(varchar(8), Date, 101) AS Date, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Name ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(8), Date, 101) DESC) My_Rank, MAX(CONVERT(varchar(8), Date, 101)) OVER (partition by ID, Name) Max_Date
            FROM    @TABLE
            GROUP   BY ID, Name, CONVERT(varchar(8), Date, 101)
        ) B 
ON  A.ID = B.ID AND CONVERT(varchar(8), A.Date, 101) = B.Max_Date
WHERE My_Rank = 1
```

Clearly, this logic is not working out. "I want to get records for ID/Name/Date based on latest processed ID/Name.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, but you don't have to join back (and you probably don't want the PARTITION BY id:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT  ID, Name, Date, 
      RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST(Date AS DATE) DESC) My_Rank
   FROM @TABLE
 ) dt
WHERE My_rank = 1
```

AFAIK SS2008 supports CAST(x AS DATE)

Comment: Hurray! Thanks dnoeth for saving me from over-complicating things (updated my query in OP)... :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `max()` with the `partition by` clause:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (select a.*,
             max("date") over (partition by id) as maxdate
      from @TABLE A
     ) a
where "date" = maxdate;
```

This can return multiple rows.  If you only one one, even when there are ties, then use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by "date" desc) as seqnum
      from @TABLE A
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I tried what you posted but it didn't work out as I wanted. I changed my output expectation to just go by the date and forget about time as abc, def, hij would have different time for the same date. Updated my expected output part of the OP.